# How do I get Activity within an espresso test?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

Im trying to use [firebase ScreenShotter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/test-screenshots#java) which takes the form:

```
ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("main_screen_2", this /* activity */);
```

I'm not exactly sure how I'm supposed to get the Activity from within an Espresso test. At the moment my test class looks something like:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class OtherTests {
    @Rule
    // Replace 'MainActivity' with the value of android:name entry in
    // <activity> in AndroidManifest.xml
    public ActivityScenarioRule <MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);




    @Test
    public void getDeviceInfo() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        TestHelper.tap("APP_HEADER");
        TestHelper.expect("TRUE_HOME_BUTTON",5000);
        ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("main_screen_2", this /* activity */);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the `scenario` and then run your code in the callback passed to `onActivity`

```java
    @Test
    public void getDeviceInfo() {
        ...
        mActivityRule.getScenario()
             .onActivity(activity -> ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("main_screen_2", activity));
         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [sample app provided by Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/test-screenshots?hl=en) (at the bottom), you can inherit from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and use the `getActivity()` method.

However, as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2), that class is deprecated in favor of `ActivityTestRule` which also has the `getActivity()` method.

```java
public void testExample() {
    // Take a screenshot when app becomes visible.
    onView(isRoot());
    ScreenShotter.takeScreenshot("main_screen_1", getActivity());
}
```

Comment: For Screenshotter I need to pass in a reference to the activity. So in your example how do you get a reference to the instance of MainActivity?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question, see my updated answer.

Comment: `ActivityTestRule` is also deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule

Comment: Should use `ActivityScenarioRule` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule